# JS Array Destructuring - Using a Binding Pattern as the Rest Property

Tags: javascript

MDN recently updated [some of their docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#using_a_binding_pattern_as_the_rest_property) and I came across the below piece of code. Can anyone explain what would be a practical use case of the following?

From MDN:

> The rest property of array destructuring assignment can be another array or object binding pattern. This allows you to simultaneously unpack the properties and indices of arrays.

```js
const [a, b, ...{ pop, push }] = [1, 2];
console.log(a, b); // 1 2
console.log(pop, push)
```

`push()` is called on an array, so what is the point of unpacking the `push()` method out of an array? I can't think of a single practical use to ever using this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<subjective>That's ... not a good example of that feature. :-D</subjective> It works because the rest element creates a new array, and then the object destructuring pattern `{ pop, push }` picks out those properties from that new array (**not** the original array).

The closest I can come to a useful example is if you want to know *how many* additional elements there were beyond the ones you wanted, but you don't want/need the actual array of them:

```js
let a, b, length;
[a, b, ...{ length }] = [1, 2];
console.log(length); // 0, there were no extra elements
[a, b, ...{ length }] = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(length); // 1, there was one extra
[a, b, ...{ length }] = [1, 2, 3, 4];
console.log(length); // 2, there were two extra
```

...but I think the fact is that while you *can* use object/array destructuring on the rest element because it falls out naturally from the way destructuring patterns work, it's unlikely to be all that useful.

---

I should note that in the more general case, using object destructuring on an array can indeed be useful, just probably not when applied to a rest element. It's especially useful for augmented arrays like the one you get from [`RegExp.prototype.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec), which includes not just the array elements for the match and any capture group values, but also `index` (where the match occurred), `input`, `groups`, and `indices`. You might want those. Object destructuring on an array lets you get the specific elements you want as well as non-element properties, for example:

```js
const str = "an example string";
const match = /example/.exec(str);
if (match) {
    const {0: matched, index } = match;
    console.log(`Matched ${JSON.stringify(matched)} at index ${index}.`);
}
```

It's also useful for picking out just a couple of elements from the middle:

```js
const array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"];
const {2: two, 7: seven} = array;
console.log(`two = ${two}, seven = ${seven}`);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the examples! I see what you mean with length. Push and pop definitely is bit of a confusing example.